# migrated to new ecommerce server. need to go back to HTTP. apache's giving me nothing

Tags: apache, magento

on centos.  we moved to shopify for a variety of reasons.

old SSL cert is no longer valid.

(1) removed everything HTTPS from my vhosts.conf file
(2) turned SSLEngine to off in my ssl.conf
(3) changed web/unsecure/base_url & web/secure/base_url to the server http IP address in the core_config_data magento DB
(4) restarted apache
(5) flushed magento cache

magento logs are blank other than `"AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 23.239.4.7:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name"` in the magento logs, so the SSL cert is still being referenced somewhere.

http admin page is still redirecting to https.

Getting "Unable to connect" at the admin page.